# What file is used during login on Unix?

Tags: unix, shell

When you log in to a shell on a Unix system there are usually some files that are run in your home directory. You'd use these to, for example, set up aliases and additions to your `$PATH`.

But, how do I know exactly which file that is? How do I figure out exactly which file I need to edit (or add)?

I'm after a generic way I can use on any Unix system. Say all you have to begin with is an IP address/hostname and a username and password for an SSH login. You connect and login. Now what do you do?

Comment: Depends on your shell. For bash, see `man bash` section `Invocation`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The profile is usually run on each login. The system-wide login file is `/etc/profile` and the user-specific files are usually `~/.profile`. Some shells have their own profile and rc files, for example bash has `.bashrc` which is run by non-login bash shells and `.bash_profile` which is run by login bash shells. The system-wide bashrc is `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Thus, you would use `.profile` for things that should be run by login shells and `.bashrc` (or an equivalent) for things that should be run by non-login shells (aliases, setting up the env and similar)

---

bash clarification:

There are two kinds of shells: login and non-login shells. A login shell is the shell run when a user logs in. Non-login shells are all other shells. For example, when you log in via `ssh` or on a console, the shell you get is a login shell.

bash login shells run at startup:

- `/etc/profile`
- The first existent file of the following: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`

bash non-login interactive shells run at startup:

- `/etc/bash.bashrc`
- `~/.bashrc`

In some (most?) unices that come with bash, the profile sources `~/.bashrc`, so `~/.bashrc` is run for both login and non-login interactive shells.

If a file does not exist it is skipped.

Comment: So there is no way to see exactly which file(s)? I just have to sort of know what might be likely? For example in this case the shell seems to be bash and uname returns SunOS. But there is no `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. There are `.profile`, `local.profile`, `local.login`, `local.cshrc`. What do I use? Are the files you mention simply missing and I should create them? Or would they not be read and I need to use one of these already here? Also, what's the difference between login shells and all shells?

Comment: For bash, you would use `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` or`.profile`. I do not know what `local.profile`, `local.login` and `local.cshrc` do, but the last one is most probably csh-specific.

Comment: So to make a "global" change to $PATH for example, I would have to add my change to both `~/.bashrc` *and* one of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile`?

Comment: If "global" means "for this user", then yes. However, the profile usually sources `~/.bashrc`, so adding the change to `~/.bashrc` would be enough.